# Object property access as function argument in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, destructor, typescript-typings

Hey I'm trying to figure out a way to properly type a function, **where one of the parameters is a property of the object**

let's say I have the following object:

```
type ThemeType = { 
   colors: {
     default: string;
     secondary: string;
     highlight: string;
     [key: string]: string;
   };
   sizes: {
     small: number | string;
     medium: number | string;
     large: number | string;
   };
}
```

---

Now i want a secondary argument in my function to access one of the properties inside the `ThemeType` type.

*Example usage would be:*

```
getThemeValue(props, colors.secondary)
// would essentially returns props.theme.color.secondary (string value)
```

---

I tried the following way:

```
interface ThemePropsType {
  theme: ThemeType
}

export const getThemeValue = <ThemePropsType, K extends keyof ThemeType>
(props: ThemePropsType, themeProperty: K) => (
   props.theme[themeProperty]
)
```

This however results in the following error:

> Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'ThemePropsType'.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: _"Example usage would be"_ - A reference error because `colors.secondary` is only available "inside" of `props.theme`.

Comment: you are probably looking for `keyof` but your example is not exactly consistent in what it is doing ..

Comment: @Andreas that's kind of what I'm trying to do. Basically I need a second argument that would access the property inside the `props.theme`